# COUNTIF text query with offset in google sheet

Tags: text, google-sheets, offset, countif

I have [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aaa0k5jxkRYF7sWTwh5XYJ9ruB8oEACTcOFGVwPSPXs/edit?usp=sharing) file with 3 different sheets.
The first contains the raw data, the second (stats) a first step of analysis and the last (WEEKLY) shows my final extrapolation.

In the WEEKLY sheet, B14 and B15, I want to count the rows from the raw data sheet that, in column G, have an "L" and a "S".

I used:

```
=COUNTIF(offset(data!$G$3,COUNT(data!$G$3:$G)-B2,0,B2,1),"L")
```

but it does not work.

I used exactly the same syntax to show positive and negative based on column R:

```
=COUNTIF(offset(data!$R$3,COUNT(data!$R$3:$R)-B2,0,B2,1),"<=0")
```

and it works pefectly as shown in the sheet WEEKLY, B9 and B10.

I can easily count Ls and Ss with a simple formula like:

```
=countif(G1:G1257,"=L")
```

but I need all the offset thinghy...

**My question is:
How can I count the S and L in the G column of the data sheet maitaining the same offset fuction I used to count positive and negative on the R column?**

Comment: OFFSET evaluates to an out of bounds range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula with column R works with COUNT because the values in column R are numeric and COUNT counts cells which contain numbers.

It doesn't work with column G because it contains text so you need to use COUNTA

```
=COUNTIF(offset(data!$G$3,COUNTA(data!$G$3:$G)-B2,0,B2,1),"L")
```